# fread performance vs benchmarking tools

Tags: c++, memory, io, fread

I'm trying to open many large sequential files (~70mb) in real time and trying to hit a target of reading ~30 files per second.
Using SSD benchmarking tools (dd on linux, winsat on windows) I can hit the advertised SSD performance of ~3200MB/s read. However, using a very simple fopen/fread app I can only hit about ~1900MB/s. Opening and reading large files (~1GB) doesn't seem to perform any better. I tried fstream and played with pubsetbuf buffer sizes. A buffer size of 1MB seems optimal but the larger I make the buffer the performance seems to drop off which surprises me.

I could buy a faster nvme drive but I feel like my current drive should be able to hit these targets if the benchmarking tools are hitting speeds above what I need.

So my question is what are the benchmarking tools doing to hit max speed? Is it possible to read files at the benchmarking speed in real life?

Thanks.

Edit:
Low level code for reference:

```
    int bytesread;
    int file = _open(entry.c_str(), _O_RDONLY | _O_BINARY | _O_SEQUENTIAL);

    off_t currentPos = _lseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    long bytes = _lseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    _lseek(file, currentPos, SEEK_SET);

    std::vector<char> buffer;
    buffer.resize(bytes);
    char* pdata = buffer.data();

    const auto startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    if ((bytesread = _read(file, pdata, bytes)) <= 0)
        perror("Problem reading file");

    const auto endTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    _close(file);
```

Edit2:
Having 2 threads using the above code produces the results I was expecting. I end up at ~2900MB/s. Using fstream is noticably slower.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you observe any performance improvements if you switch from fopen()/fread() to open/read() ?

Comment: No change. I've edited my original post with the code.